# Qt how to embedded image resource in custom widget plugin dll and make it available in qt designer resource chooser dialog

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qt-resource

I have implemented a qt custom widget (MyWidget) plugin which can be used in qt designer. There is a property IconImg of MyWidget with which user can provide an image file to change the icon of MyWidget. Now, I want to embedded several default images for it. Then, user can easily choose the preferred one.

My question is, in qt, how to embedded image resource in custom widget plugin dll and make it available in qt designer resource chooser dialog?

Comment: Did you try `Q_INIT_RESOURCE()`?

Comment: yes, I tried. does not work